# Помощь в понимании JS

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```
function f(c) {
    c--;
    document.write("<p>" + c);

    if (c != 0) {
        f(c);
    }
    document.write("<p>" + c);
}

f(3);
```

**Output: 
2
1
0
0
1
2**

**Вопрос, почему функция не заканчивается после второго нуля ("0") а продолжает печатать 1 и 2 ?**

Comment: Потому что у вас два `document.write` до и после рекурсивного вызова

Comment: `return f(c);` надо

Comment: @Pavel. a это не вы :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306104/why-the-code-is-executing-again-after-the-if-condition-returning-false-value#47306104 ?

Comment: @splash58  :) Нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте заменим переменные их реальными значениями и посмотрим, что получится.

Итак, вызов `f(3);` разворачивается в такое

```js
3--;
document.write("<p>" + 2);
if (2 != 0) {
  2--;
  document.write("<p>" + 1);
  if (1 != 0) {
    1--;
    document.write("<p>" + 0);
    if (0 != 0) {

    }
    document.write("<p>" + 0);
  }
  document.write("<p>" + 1);
}
document.write("<p>" + 2);
```

Comment: Лучшее объяснение!